# New-Team not returning the groupID

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a powershell script that creates a new team using the New-Team module. This should output the newly created teams GroupID, i don't seem to get this but the Team is created just fine.

The code i'm using is:

```
$team = New-Team -MailNickname $TeamName -displayname $TeamName -Visibility Private
```

Write-Host "Team Created: $TeamName"
Write-Host "Team GUID: $team.GroupID"

The response i get from $team.GroupID is the following and not the value.

```
Team GUID: Microsoft.Teams.PowerShell.TeamsCmdlets.Model.TeamSettings.GroupID
```

Comment: What does `$Team.GroupID |Get-Member` show you?

Comment: I get " Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quoting an object. Try the following:

```
Write-Host "Team GUID: $($team.GroupID)"
```

So basically what you are outputting is:

```
"Team GUID: $team(the complete object) .GroupID(in plain text)"
```

You could however also do it outside quotes:

```
Write-Host "Team GUID: " + $team.GroupID
```